# Unable to connect to a DB2 distante database using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2

Tags: database, vb.net, db2, driver, oledb

**Code**:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=DB2OLEDB;Data Source=@IP;Persist Security Info=False;Password=UserPWD;User ID=UserID;Database Name=@IP;Network Address=@IP;Package Collection=QGPL"
            con.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur Message : " & ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur HelpLink: " & ex.HelpLink)
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur Source: " & ex.Source)
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur TargetSite: " & ex.TargetSite.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

***Error Message:***

> The host resource could not be found. Check that the Initial Catalog value matches the host resource name.

***Error StackTrace:***

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
>
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions  options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>
> TestConnection.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans C:\Users...\Form1.vb:ligne 8

***Error Source:***

> Microsoft DB2 OLE DB Provider

***Error TargetSite:***

> Void .ctor(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)

***Note:*** The same program works on my co-worker's PC

**My PC configuration:** Win 8.1 Pro 64 bits

**His PC configuration:** Win 7 Pro 64 bits

We are using **Cisco Any connect Secure Mobility Client VPN** and **DB2 provider V 4.0**

Answer (score 0):

your connectionstring is wrong

try Something like this

```
con.ConnectionString="Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=urDataBase;Hostname=urServerAddress;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Uid=urUsername;Pwd=urPassword;"
```

you must change urDataBase, urServerAddress, urUsername and urPassword  values of course